# Entity Framework Migration From Command Line

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework

Is it possible doing some entity framework migration commands from a lightweight command line like visual studio cl?

I can't access to my remote sql express server from local visual studio so I can't add-migration and update-database commands. So if there would be a cl, I could solve my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a Migrate.exe tool which comes with EF which you can run through the command line.

Documentation for it can be found at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618307.aspx

Used something like:

```
Migrate.exe MyApp.exe /startupConfigurationFile=”MyApp.exe.config” /targetMigration=”myTargetMigration”
```